# Solutions $m(m+1)=2^T(2^U-1)$ in natural $m,T,U$ other than $m+1=2^T$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a small problem in working on a bigger one, and possibly this is very easy and I'm only dense at the moment.

It seems to me that in
$$ m(m+1) = 2^T(2^U-1) \qquad \qquad m,T,U \in \mathbb N
$$
we can have solutions only when $m+1=2^T$, arguing in the following way:

- $m$ and $m+1$ cannot have common factors and as well $2^T$ and $2^U-1$ cannot have common factors. So with $m'=m+1$ we have the parallel factorization $$m'(m'-1) = 2^T(2^U-1)$$
- from where also follows that $U=T$

but didn't I miss something?

---

***update*** I should give a bit more background to avoid useless thinking. The question occurs in the consideration of the existence of $2$-odd-steps-cycles in the generalized Collatz-problem $mx+1$. From this, $m$ is odd, and $2^S$ is the next power of $2$ above $m^2$ and $S$ is odd. I've already a very sparse set of possible combinations of $S$ and $m$. For the accessibility of the problem I assume the nontrivial $2$-step-cycle as $a \to b \to a \to ...$ with $a=1,b>1$ and arrive at the given formula.  The $2^U$ comes from  $2^U=2^{S-T}$ and $T$ given by $m+1=2^T \cdot w$ with $w$ odd.
I asked the question without that background because I thought, that the formula itself is sufficient to say generalities about characteristics of sets of solutions.

Comment: You can also have $m+1=2^U-1$ and $m=2^T$, but this implies $2^U=2^T+2$ and forces $T=1,U=2$. If $2^U-1=ab$ such that $a$ and $2^Tb$ are consequtive, that is also a possibility. But I don't if it gives more solutions. No time to think.

Comment: $2$ is prime and according to [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) will divide either $m$ or $m+1$. Thus $2^T \mid m$ or $2^T \mid m+1$ (also because $\gcd(m,m+1)=1$).

Comment: Also $2\cdot (2^4-1)=2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 6\cdot 5=5\cdot(5+1)$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $ab=cd$ with $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$ and the integers positive, implies that $a$ must be one of $c$ or $d$. The example $3 \cdot 10=5\cdot 6$ demonstrates the problem with this.

Comment: In case $T=1$, your problem is connected to the classical Ramanujan-Nagell equation --- this is where the solution with $m=5$ comes from (as does the slightly more "interesting" one with $m=-91$).

Comment: @MikeBennett - your first comment: yes, I got this more transparent meanwhile (by hint by rtybase). Still not really handable, but it still "flows" (in my mind...) . Second comment: I'll look to get the connection to R-N-equ. The problem stems from the generalized Collatz-problem $mx+1$ and the specific question of existence of 2-odd-step-cycles with $a_1=1$ and $a_2>1$. For $m=5$ we have a solution of this form ($1 \to 3 \to 1 \to ...$). Why is $m=-91$ interesting?

Comment: @Servaes - I agree to your first comment. That was something my instinct warned me about but I coldn't grasp it explicitely and firmly in the morning. Thus asking here for mind-openers and not stepping into a trap... :)

Comment: @MikeBennett - concerning Ramanujan-Nagell-equation. I've checked in wikipedia. Funny, $m=181$ seems aside of $m=5$ to be the only value for which the generalized Collatz problem has $2$-step-cycles. One $2$-odd-step-cycle on $m=181$ has already been found by R.E.Crandall in 1978 and I've later come across the second one. This here is another attempt to characterize the existence of such cycles in general (don't know whether even this small problem might be out of reach for me though...)

Comment: $(m,T,U)=(5,1,4),(90,1,12)$ for $m\le 10^8$.

Comment: @MikeBennet - I found now the significance of the $-91$-solution. It means that with the generalized Collatz-problem  of the form $mx+1$ with $m=-91$ we have a $2$-odd-step cycle $1 \to -45 \to 1 \to \cdots $ . So it seems I'm getting a good heuristic that all of my solutions $a=1$ and $b=(m\cdot a +1)/2^{v_2(m\cdot a +1)}$ so far are also all *possible* $2$-odd-step-cycles in the $mx+1$-problem with odd $-\infty \lt m \lt \infty$ and $a=1$. I'm still fiddling with an idea how to do an elementary proof , but it seems really difficult...